eslint new flat config not working with typescript-eslint and eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y
I'm trying to migrate to a new flat config of eslint, but typescript-eslint and eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y not connecting as expected. I read from the docs of these packages how to connect to flat config, but it's still not working. I got an errors while building: Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any' was not found, Definition for rule 'jsx-a11y/control-has-associated-label' was not found and others. All errors from typescript-eslint and eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y.
code:
import path from 'node:path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url'
import js from '@eslint/js'
import { FlatCompat } from '@eslint/eslintrc'
import globals from 'globals'

import react from 'eslint-plugin-react'
import unicorn from 'eslint-plugin-unicorn'
import eslintConfigPrettier from 'eslint-config-prettier'
import importPlugin from 'eslint-plugin-import'
import jsxA11y from 'eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y'
import eslintPluginPrettierRecommended from 'eslint-plugin-prettier/recommended'
import eslintPluginUnicorn from 'eslint-plugin-unicorn'
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint'

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename)
const compat = new FlatCompat({
  baseDirectory: __dirname,
  recommendedConfig: js.configs.recommended,
  allConfig: js.configs.all,
})

export default tseslint.config([
  {
    ignores: ['**/node_modules', '**/*.js'],
  },
  ...compat.extends('airbnb', 'airbnb-typescript', 'airbnb/hooks'),
  importPlugin.flatConfigs.recommended,
  jsxA11y.flatConfigs.recommended,
  reactPlugin.configs.flat.recommended,
  reactPlugin.configs.flat['jsx-runtime'],
  eslintPluginUnicorn.configs['flat/recommended'],
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
  {
    plugins: {
      react,
      '@typescript-eslint': tseslint.plugin,
      unicorn,
    },
    languageOptions: {
      ...reactPlugin.configs.flat.recommended.languageOptions,
      globals: {
        ...globals.browser,
        ...globals.es2021,
      },
      parser: tseslint.parser,
      parserOptions: {
        project: true,
      },
    },
    rules: {
      'import/prefer-default-export': 'off',
      'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 'off',
      'react/require-default-props': 'off',
      'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
      'react/display-name': 'off',
      'react/no-unstable-nested-components': [
        'error',
        {
          allowAsProps: true,
        },
      ],
      'no-param-reassign': [
        'error',
        {
          props: true,
          ignorePropertyModificationsFor: ['draft'],
        },
      ],
      '@typescript-eslint/array-type': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/ban-types': [
        'error',
        {
          types: {
            Node: 'Node is disabled, use HTMLElement',
          },
        },
      ],
      '@typescript-eslint/await-thenable': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-for-in-array': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-arguments': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion': 'error',

      '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions': [
        'error',
        {
          assertionStyle: 'as',
        },
      ],
      '@typescript-eslint/prefer-nullish-coalescing': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/switch-exhaustiveness-check': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/prefer-for-of': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-extra-non-null-assertion': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-asserted-optional-chain': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/prefer-optional-chain': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/require-await': 'error',
      'unicorn/filename-case': [
        'error',
        {
          case: 'kebabCase',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  eslintConfigPrettier,
  eslintPluginPrettierRecommended,
])


You can use npx eslint --debug filename.js for debugging. I also don't really get the new flat config file working like it should as it always ignores my typescript files, hope you have more success!
